# subconsulta com 3 tabelas diferentes usando ilike no postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

Pessoal estou com uma dúvida. Como faço  uma busca de um determinado texto usando ilike para saber se esse texto  existe em 3 tabelas relacionadas. ?Tentei existe mas não deu

```
CREATE TABLE metodo (
    id SERIAL NOT NULL,
    descricao CHARACTER VARYING NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE forma (
    id SERIAL NOT NULL,
    id_metodo INTEGER,
    descricao CHARACTER VARYING NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE acao (
    id SERIAL NOT NULL,
    id_forma INTEGER,
    descricao CHARACTER VARYING NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: Mostre a estrutura das tabelas e os campos de texto.

Comment: `sql`  CREATE TABLE metodo
(
  id        SERIAL            NOT NULL,
  descricao CHARACTER VARYING NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE forma (
  id        SERIAL            NOT NULL,
  id_metodo INTEGER,
  descricao CHARACTER VARYING NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE acao (
  id        SERIAL            NOT NULL,
  id_forma  INTEGER,
  descricao CHARACTER VARYING NOT NULL
);  `sql`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Que tal utilizar o `UNION`:

```
SELECT 'M', id, descricao FROM metodo WHERE descricao ILIKE '%texto%'
UNION
SELECT 'F', id, descricao FROM forma WHERE descricao ILIKE '%texto%'
UNION
SELECT 'A', id, descricao FROM acao WHERE descricao ILIKE '%texto%'
```